# Angular 2 property binding unexpectedly triggered

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have a component to edit date ranges (effective and expire dates). When either of the dates change, it emits the new date range. However, after the emission, the `@Input() set dateRange(...)` gets called. Is this the expected behavior? If so, why would the parent  component set the binded child component property when it just gets a new value from the child?

```
export class EditDateRange {
  effectiveDate?: Date;
  expireDate?: Date;

  @Output() dateRangeChange = new EventEmitter<DateRange>();

  @Input()
  get dateRange(): DateRange {
    return new DateRange({
      effectiveDate: this.effectiveDate,
      expireDate: this.expireDate,
    });
  }

  // Gets called when dateRangeChange emitts an event
  set dateRange(dateRange: DateRange) {
    if (dateRange.hasEffectiveDate) {...}
    if (dateRange.hasExpireDate) {...}
  }

  dateRangeChanged() {
    this.dateRangeChange.emit(this.dateRange);
  }
}
```

Then in parent HTML

```
<div>
    ...
    <edit-date-range [(dateRange)]="dateRange" 
                     (dateRangeChange)="validateDateRange($event)">
    </edit-date-range>
</div>
```

The problem (or maybe, the behavior) goes away when I change `[(dateRange)]` to `[dateRange]`.

Comment: What do you mean it gets called again? Is it called twice after the emit?

Comment: Just once, it gets called after the emit. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Yes it is, since you are using two way binding. Your output changes the parent value which in turn changes the input of the child.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I also noticed that the date range object that the parent receives is slightly modified when it is passed to the input of the child, how could this happen?

Comment: I cant tell from the code I see.

Answer (score 0):

`[(dateRange)]` would be two way binding and already a lifecycle hook for change detection so it's behaving as expected. `[dateRange]` would be one way binding and no longer acts as a lifecycle hook. Instead of manually handling the event emission I would instead utilize [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) to utilize the lifecycle hook already in play.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ngModel banana in box documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---):

> The [(x)] syntax is easy to demonstrate when the element has a settable property called x and a corresponding event named xChange.
>   `<app-sizer [(size)]="fontSizePx"></app-sizer>`

And farther down:

> The two-way binding syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a property binding and an event binding. Angular desugars the SizerComponent binding into this:
>   `<app-sizer [size]="fontSizePx" (sizeChange)="fontSizePx=$event"></app-sizer>`

That being said, using two way binding as well as the change event binding will cause the change to be triggered twice.